# Rails: Dynamically convert last quartet of IPv4 address to wildcard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, gsub, ipv4

I am looking for the regex/gsub combination to do below for any number in the last quartet.

```
irb(main):008:0> ip = "192.168.1.255"
=> "192.168.1.255"
irb(main):009:0> ip.gsub("255", "*")
=> "192.168.1.*"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does something like this meet your needs?

```
ip.sub(/^([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.)[0-9]+/, $1 + '*' )
```

or better...

```
ip.sub(/^([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+/, $1 + '*' )
```

or better still...

```
ip.sub(/\d+$/, '*')
```

Comment: Hi Dave, are you able to convert the last n quartets? e.g. "192.1.23.45" => "192.1.*.*" or "192.*.*.*"?